# A book my brother-in-law read when he was growing-up in the 70's/80's, possibly post-apocalyptic.

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, post-apocalyptic, dystopia

It sounds like a post-apocalyptic story from what he told me.  The only details he could give me other than that was a character called *Kincaid* (unsure of spelling) and a group called *the Kriss* (again unsure of spelling).  Sorry for such sketchy details.

Comment: Earth: Final Conflict has a character called Liam Kincaid and in several episodes there is a drug called Kryss. This obviously isn't what your brother in law remembers, but I wonder if there has been some confusion of memories.

Comment: Thanks John.  I'll pass this on and see if it jogs BIL's memory.  Don't know why not knowing this bugs me so much but it does.

Answer (score 3):

"[The Masters of Solitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Masters_of_Solitude)", by Marvin Kaye and Parke Godwin is a post-apocalypse novel that features the Kriss, the last surviving militant fundamentalist Christians.

There's nobody named Kincaid, but there is a lot of mention of a semi-mythical historical figure named Callee or McCallee. The Kriss and the Circle (telepathic Wiccans) are at war with each other, and the story of Calleee may hold the key to a lost piece of technology that can end the war.

[image]